# Python Pool Map() Gives ether Pickle Error Or Does Not Iterate List Properly

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I have a function that takes a list of urls and adds a header to each url. The url_list can be about 25,000 long lists. So, I want to use multiprocessing. I have tried 2 ways both with failure:

First way- the url_list is not passing correctly...the function only gets the first letter 'h' of the url_list url:

```
headers = {}
header_token = {}

def do_it(url_list):
    for i in url_list:
    print "adding header to: \n" + i
    requests.post(i, headers=headers)
    print "done!"

 value = raw_input("Proceed? Enter [Y] for yes: ")
    if value == "Y":
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(do_it, url_list)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "head.py", line 95, in <module>
    pool.map(do_it, url_list)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'h': No schema supplied
```

The second way...the way I prefer since I don't have to make headers dictionary global. But I get a pickle error:

```
def wrapper(headers):
    def do_it(url_list):
    for i in url_list:
        print "adding header to: \n" + i
        requests.post(i, headers=headers)
    print "done!"
    return do_it

    value = raw_input("Proceed? Enter [Y] for yes: ")
    if value == "Y":
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(wrapper(headers), url_list)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use your second implementation, then I think you should be able to use [dill](http://pythonhosted.org/dill) to serialize your wrapper function. Dill can serialize almost anything in python. Dill also has [some good tools](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/detect.py) for helping you understand what is causing your pickling to fail when your code fails. Dill has the same interface as python's `pickle`, but also provides some additional methods.  If you want to use dill for serialization with `multiprocessing`, all you have to do is:

```
>>> import dill
>>> # your code goes here (as above)
```

And, if that doesn't work for some reason, you could swap out `multiprocessing` with [pathos](http://pythonhosted.org/pathos)... which is built to do multiprocessing using dill -- and provides a multi-*args `map` function (exactly like the standard python `map`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Queue from the multiprocessing package. The datatype that your pulling from or adding to needs to be thread and process safe; a Queue is both.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes